# Angular how to check a checkbox with [checked] attribute and key value pair?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

How do you use [checked] attribute in Angular, alongside key value pair values, that are gotten from backend server? I am receiving data from a response like this:

```
[{"endpoint":"/profile"},{"endpoint":"/settings"},{"endpoint":"/payments"},{"endpoint":"/login"},{"endpoint":"/accounts"},{"endpoint":"/v2/accounts/*"}]
```

My checkboxes are dynamically generated. All of the available endpoints are listed from a enabledEndpoints list in the component.ts class, then I want them to be checked, if they are returned in the http response and placed into profileEndpoints object. The object has one variable which is `endpoint: string`. This is the markup code for it:

```
<label for="enabledEndpoints">Enabled Endpoints</label>
<tr *ngFor="let endpoint of enabledEndpoints;">
  <td class="pr-4 pl-3">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
             id="{{endpoint}}"
             [value]="endpoint"
             [checked]="profileEndpoints.includes(endpoint)"
             name="enabledEndpoints">
      <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="endpoint">
        {{ endpoint }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How do I make them checked using the [checked] attribute? I have tried include functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `profileEndpoints` is an object with one property `endpoint` please change the code as below.

in controller add this.

```
isChecked(endpoint: string): boolean {
    return !!(this.profileEndpoints.find(x => x.endpoint === endpoint))
}
```

html it will be

```
<label for="enabledEndpoints">Enabled Endpoints</label>
<tr *ngFor="let endpoint of enabledEndpoints;">
  <td class="pr-4 pl-3">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
             id="{{endpoint}}"
             [value]="endpoint"
             [checked]="isChecked(endpoint)"
             name="enabledEndpoints">
      <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="endpoint">
        {{ endpoint }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working, throws a Parser Error.

Comment: @dovexz12323
 what is the full error, can I get a stackblitz

Comment: Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 26 in [profileEndpoints.find(x => x.endpoint === endpoint)]

Comment: @dovexz12323 modified my answer!

Comment: Works great, valid answer, thank you.